# Ocaml - Smalltofront in Selection sort

Tags: algorithm, ocaml

Basically I think I have done everything correct for the swap and selectionsort function, but my *smalltofront* function is the one that's incorrect.

The problem is that I can't figure out how this should be (please see the whole code beneath):

```
 else (if a.(k) < a.(s)
    then smalltofront (a,s,i+1,j,k)
    else smalltofront (a,s,i+1,j,k));;
```

- a = array
- s = start of the unsorted subarray
- i = the moving index from left to right
- j = the right most index
- k = is the current index to the smallest entry

What have I done wrong?

```
let swap (a,i,j) =
let temp = a.(i)
in (a.(i)<-a.(j);
a.(j)<-temp);;



let rec smalltofront (a,s,i,j,k) =
if i>j
then swap (a,s,k)
else (if a.(k) < a.(s)
then smalltofront (a,s,i+1,j,k)
else smalltofront (a,s,i+1,j,k));;


let rec selectionsort (a,i,j) = 
if i>j
then ()
else smalltofront (a,i,i,j,i); selectionsort (a,i+1,j);;
```

Comment: Can you, please, elaborate a bit more and tell us what you are trying to achieve and what doesn't work?

Comment: The function smalltofront won't work. I am trying to get the smallest element to front of the array.

Comment: "won't work" is not a useful problem statement. To be able to help you we need to know what you expect it to do, as well as what the code you have now actually does. If you're not able to answer either of those, then the process of figuring that out might even help you solve the problem on your own.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that  you don't change `k` through recursive calls to `smalltofront`. Once you find the new smallest element it should become new `k`. So the correct solution will be:

```
let rec smalltofront (a, s, i, j, k) =
    if i > j then swap (a, s, k)
    else (
        if a.(k) < a.(i) then
            smalltofront (a, s, i+1, j, k)
        else smalltofront (a, s, i+1, j, i)
    )
```

Also notice that you forgot the parenthesis in the `else` branch of `selectionsort`:

```
let rec selectionsort (a, i, j) = 
    if i > j then ()
    else (smalltofront (a, i, i, j, i);
          selectionsort (a, i + 1, j))
```

Also don't forget that your implementation demand to call `selectionsort` with `Array.length a - 1` as the last argument.

Now, I don't now why you trying to write this function, but I suppose you are rather new to OCaml and maybe this is some sort of training. If I'm right then I would like to say that using arrays is not the greatest way to learn OCaml and functional programming in general, for the beginning try to avoid mutable types. Also note that when you write something like this: `smalltofront (a, s, i, j, k)` you in fact define function with one argument `(a, s, i, j, k)` which is a tuple, and even if it works, maybe you mean something different, you can simply write `smalltofront a s i j k`.

Comment: Thank you so much! The functions works without Array.length, why would I implement it?

Comment: @EricSand No, what I mean is that, for example this code: `selectionsort ([|1; 2|], 0, 2)`, will fail, because `2` is greater than `Array.length [|1; 2|] - 1`.

Comment: Vonaka, thank you so very much! Do you know how to do a similar algorithm but for insertion sort?

Comment: @EricSand I'm pretty much sure that I know how to do this, but I'm also sure that no one on this site will write code for you. Try your best to do it yourself and create new post if you encounter any interesting problems.